# How to connect two clients from the server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a simple chat program using Java. I have create TCP server that accepts multiple clients. Currently the clients message to server.

1. How can I broadcast the message from one client to all the others?
2. How can I pair of two clients. Send and recieve message to eachother?

Comment: Are you trying to make a peer to peer chat?

Comment: yes. Client to server to client connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How can I broadcast the message from one client to all the others?

Use a subscribe/notify mechanism

> 2.How can I pair of two clients. Send and recieve message to eachother?

Clients must have a server socket listening as well.

**UPDATE:**
Your server will have some sort of registry where all your clients register for notifications.
The clients open a server socket that waits for messages.
When a client wants to send a message then it connects to the server, sends the message and the server can either send the message to all registered clients or to a specific client that is supposed to receive the message.At this part the server connects to the client's server socket and sends the message.
Another option is not to open a server socket at the client, but the client does polling to see if the server has a message available

Comment: The client has the socket listening. How can I connect the clients with each otehr from server ?

Comment: The client connects to the server's socket and send messages to the server.You have to open a server socket to your client as well so that it can accepts connections from other clients/peers.Unless you want to use the server as sort of intermediary.What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes. I want the server to mediate the communication as any user can try to connect to any other user. The server will find the correct target and then join them.

Comment: Updated answer according to this

Answer (score 3):

You can make your clients communicate through simple sockets. Once the server sends the IP of the clients, you can use the IP and the TCP port of the client (usually 443) to communicate. I know in C its done this way I am not sure if you can use this in your Java implementation but something similar will work.

```
//#define MSG "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"     
 char   buffer[128]= "0"; 

    struct sockaddr_in      sin; 
    struct hostent           *host; 
    int                           s; 

    host = gethostbyname("Clients IP");  

    memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length); 
    //sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("175.41.153.196");
    sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype; 
    //sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(443);
    // Create socket port 443
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    // 1. Block for server accept 
    connect(s,  (struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));     
    // 2. Send "Hello world"       
    send(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);   
    // 3. Block for receive 
    recv(s,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    // Print received data


    close(s);

    //return 0;
```

You can then use the Send and recv function to send and receive between your clients.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Multi Threading concept in this.
I think this link will be helpful.
http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a thread that will handle a ServerSocket to accept
   connections.
2. Make the clients send a unique identificator to the server upon
   connection.
3. When a client sends a message, use the id of the desired receiver
   client as a parameter, or empty so send to all clients.